# Pass data to Servlet on a button click

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which displays the images from the servlet along with its name and category. And in Jsp page each image has a button to click on.
Now my problem is how to send the data (name and category) of an image on a button click to the servlet. So that in servlet, i can perform some activity based on the name and category.

I tried using `<input type= "hidden" name= "name" value= <%= value%> >`, i am getting the values of the last image displayed in the jsp, whatever button i clicked in Jsp.

Can any body help me in this regard.

Thank you.